# Problems compiling my first java Application

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm newbie with Java and I don't know if this is because I'm doing something wrong.

My app is not too complicated. It has 5 packages. One of them, the `carlosgoce` package has the `App` class with the `main` method. From there, I instantiate my `Principal` class which extends `JFrame` on package `gui.Principal`.

So, my `App` class is something like this:

```
package carlosgoce;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import gui.Principal;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Principal ventana = new Principal();
        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
        ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        ventana.setVisible(true);                        
    }        
}
```

Ventana means Window by the way.

So `Principal` is just a `JFrame`.

My App works perfectly when i click the "play" button on Netbeans. When I try to use the generated jar it just say that it can't be opened. I check on my project properties and check if the `main` class was selected, and it was / it is. I read on stackoverflow to disable "Compile on save". I did, but it didn't help.

When I try to open the .jar file it just doesn't work. I tried with Clean/Build also.

Then I realized that the JFrame class autogenerated by Netbeans also had a `main` method so I commented it (I don't know if a project can have multiples main methods). The app is still working when launched from Netbeans but not from the jar file.

Maybe it's because of Maven? First time using it also. I found that is similar to composer on PHP. I just add OpenCSV dependency.

I just don't know what to do next. Some help?

Thank you!

More info:
This is my current pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>carlosgoce</groupId>
    <artifactId>distribuir.articulos</artifactId>
    <version>1.02-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>distribuir.articulos</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                      <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>carlosgoce.principal.App</mainClass>
                      </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attached</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>           
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If i compile it with clean/build from Netbeans i got this manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: acliente7
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_25
Main-Class: carlosgoce.principal.App
Class-Path: opencsv-2.0.jar
```

Looks great but i can't find the opencsv-2.0.jar inside the .jar file and the app it doesn't work.

If i compile my project with cleand and then "build with dependencies" i got this manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: 23.25-b01 (Oracle Corporation)
```

So the "Class-Path: opencsv-2.0.jar" and more lines with the info of my project are missing. BUT the opencsv IS inside my .jar file.

Any tip?

FIXED compiling the app with the command
mvn clean compile assembly:single

I don't know if i have to do something with the question

Comment: Do you get an error? Please provide more details.

Comment: It may be because your jar does not include all dependencies. Check your project settings and make sure that everything is in place there.

Comment: There is more. I tried creating a new simple project. I created a project with just a Main class, autogenerated by netbeans and add a simple System.out.println("test"); I click on "clean/build", then, i go trough the terminal, move to the project directory and tried with Java test.jar and it said "Main class not found". So i wonder if is some kind of issue with netbeans? using 7.4 on Mac.

Comment: Jar files built by Maven are not runnable by default. You have to specify the main class (i.e. the class containing the main method). See https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Make.

Comment: Is the jar containing Principal in the classpath?

Comment: The main class is designated by the Manifest within the .jar file. If that does not contain the correct information then your .jar won't run. Furthermore, if you simply "open" the .jar file in your operating system, then your .jar should be executed by running `java -jar [yourapp.jar]` otherwise it won't run.

Comment: My simple Test application is working indeeed with the java -jar (i forget the -jar param). Sorry! I'm pretty sure that the problem is with Maven. Checking billc hint.

Comment: Okay so you have to place the main file name in the MANIFEST.MF and include it into your jar. And this is how you do this: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: I updated the question with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assembly:single` is not needed, just add executions configuration to your pom

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id> 
        <phase>package</phase> 
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you. Now i can compile my app from Netbeans!